# Problems with Cocoapods and firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I am currently trying to add firebase to my Xcode project. I am using Xcode 11.  The problem is with the actual cocoapods because now none of my projects using cocapods will build. im currently running cocoapods 1.9.3. All my errors fall under GoogleDataTransport and it says theyre all "lexical or preprocessor issue"s. Any help would be great!

Comment: It's a good idea to include your podfile, version of XCode and OS so we know how that looks. Also it's not working is quite vague so please clarify what that means specifically. Your error is probably related to what's in your podfile as there were some changes to Firebase not too long ago - we ran into the same issue recently as well when were were updating a few projects. Also, you may need to update cocoapods again `sudo gem install cocoapods` or remove it and reinstall. Catalina: `sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error is related to [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5987) issue.

To fix it, you have to modify the build settings.

1. Select your Pods Project
2. Go to Build Settings
3. Set `Quoted Include In Framework Header` to `NO`

[image: screenshot]